# React Native reading JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I have a JSON request, that returns a JSON objects;

```
 {
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "zy8y9DkaOiYwKh0aStoEqOU_knU",
  "nextPageToken": "CBQQAA",
  "regionCode": "GB",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 40,
    "resultsPerPage": 20
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "tvnouv0ap06XQKjt95dVECc_VZ4",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "Qiyk-s60rgo"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-04-30T10:00:46Z",
        "channelId": "UCa_6KiOjxm6dEC_mMRP5lGA",
        "title": "Derby Futsal Club - Goal of the Season 2019/20 | Tom Gascoyne vs Birmingham",
        "description": "Derby Futsal Club's Goal of the Season as voted for by the public went to Tom Gascoyne for his goal against Birmingham in the National Futsal Series on 3rd ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qiyk-s60rgo/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qiyk-s60rgo/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qiyk-s60rgo/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Derby Futsal",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-04-30T10:00:46Z"
      }
    },
```

I'm reading the JSON like so;

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch(playertype(typeOfProfile))
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    setData(json)
    })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, []);

return (
<View style={styles.body}>
  {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
    <FlatList
    data={data[0]}
      horizontal={true}
      keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={stylesB.container}>
          <Image style={styles.img} source={{ uri: chkValueI(item.items.snippet.medium.url) }} />
        </View>
      )}
    />
  )}
</View>
);
};
```

I'm reading the data as data[0] so I hit the first object, and then finding the property I want (the image) by using item.items.snippet.medium.url, but this doesn't return anything.

My question is;

Can I specify the object I want to get by using data[0] and then reference a property using item.items.snippet.medium.url?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to filter the JSON? i see that you are using a flatlist to show that

Comment: Hi @GuruparanGiritharan, at present on this JSON response, I can't parse it to read the URL for the medium image that gets returned. Its moaning that the JSON is an object, and when I try to read values it won't let me (I get a NaN error). If I was filtering I'd normally use; <FlatList
          data={data.filter(data => data.xxx == xxx)}
          horizontal={true}

Answer (score 1):

> Can I specify the object I want to get by using data[0] and then
>   reference a property using item.items.snippet.medium.url?

Flat list requires a data array so you dont need a flatlist to display a single item. You can simply use the renderItem function and pass the first item.

> item.items.snippet.medium.url

Here the items is an array so you should use something like below to access the item. Better check the array length before doing this. Or go for a map to map the values.

```
item.items[0].snippet.medium.url
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Guruparan, I'm actually wanting to loop through the JSON to display multiple records, I'm guessing I need to map them :)

Comment: You are already using a flat list so set the data array directly and use it as flatlists are recommended over using map for performance reasons

Comment: Thanks Guruparan, that was what I was attempting at first (as you mention Im already using the flatlist), the problem is when I reference just data={data} I get NaN error (assuming this is an out of bounds due to the json being an object).

Comment: If you know of any good examples I can look @, please could you share here as its a challenge I think I'll face more than just YouTube API integration :)